# CSS/HTML 2x2 Grid Issue

Tags: html, css, grid

This question has come up similarly before, but I have looked around and can't find this happening to anyone else.

I can make a 4x4 grid of divs together with images using  in the HTML but one of the divs I want text in (top right). When I enter `<p>Some text</p>` within that div it goes below the div to the left and the bottom two are still aligned and under the moved text div.

I have tried making the height fixed but nothing changed, the div just moved up but the others remained where they were.

CSS:

```
/* Page Content */

.container
    {width: 910px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 35px;
    position: relative;}

/* Home Page Content */

.gridblock, .gridblock2, .gridtext
    {width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;}

.gridblock
    {margin: 2px;}

.gridblock2, .gridtext
    {margin: 3px, 0px, 3px, 0px;}

.gridtext
    {width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gridblock">
        <img src="images/homegrid1.jpg" alt="3345 Mastering">
    </div>
    <div class="gridtext">
        <p>Some Text</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="gridblock">
        <img src="images/homegrid2.jpg" alt="3345 Mastering">
    </div>
    <div class="gridblock2">
        <img src="images/homegrid3.jpg" alt="3345 Mastering">
    </div>
    <ul class="footer">
    </ul>
```

This is an online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/2LCwg/

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle? Because I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I have made a demo look again at the end of edited version of the question.

Comment: As I said, all I can see is this http://i45.tinypic.com/5of4n5.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting your question right, the problem seems to be with the property `display:inline-block`.

Add `vertical-align:top` to your `.gridtext` class:

```
.gridtext {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

It should fix it. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCwg/2/).

And [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/%22here%22)'s an interesting article about the display:inline-block property.

Alternatively, you could remove the `display:inline-block` property (your divs would then, by default, be displayed as block) and give them floats instead:

```
.gridblock, .gridblock2, .gridtext {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Also, as you are working with images, you could add `overflow:hidden` to the above classes, to make sure those images won't expand out of its container and mess up the grid.

```
.gridblock, .gridblock2 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the vertical-align worked perfectly. Sorry my description wasn't fully understandable and thank you for the alternative I am about to try that out now.

Comment: Sure, no problem =) On the alternative, just make sure the floats will work for you, they may have other implications on your layout.